# Why is axios cookie undefined?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

When I try to hit an endpoint with postman everything works, so I assume the problem is probably with my axios request as when logging `req.headers.cookies` on server after performing this axios request the value is `undefined`.

Cookies in browser work as well they are set correctly.

When i performed this request in postman the value of `req.headers.cookie` was fine and the request has been performed without any errors.

Client code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/refresh_token', {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```

Server code (endpoint function):

```
export const validateRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers.cookie); // undefined
  const { token } = parse(req.headers.cookie);

  ...
};
```

Error message: `TypeError argument str must be a string.`
This error points to the parse function.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any ides on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Axios `POST`, 1st arg is the `url`, 2nd arg is `data` and the 3rd arg is for `options`.

Provide `withCredentials: true` in the 3rd argument of `Axios.post`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/refresh_token', {} ,{
        withCredentials: true,
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```